# A pattern related combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of permutations of the 12 letters 
       A,C,D,G,H,I,K,N,O,R,S,T
 which do not contain the pattern
        KRISHNA.

- My attempt:I found the number of ways of arranging these 12 letters after that I assumed the pattern Krishna as a single letter and by subtraction I got 12!-6!7! as the number of permutation not containing the given pattern . But I was unable to get the result can anybody tell me where is the flaw and what is the correct solution . Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You were close:
$12!$ are all the possible permutations. KRISHNA is of length 7, then by joining it into 'one letter' we are left with 6 letters to permutate. Substract $12! - 6! $ and you should get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

None of the letters are being repeated. So you have 12 distinct objects, and KRISHNA is 7 out of them.

So if you just let X represent KRISHNA, you get:

_
_
_
_
_
_

Now you have 6 objects, and you have to find the number of permutations you can make with these 6 objects without restrictions. This is the total number of ways the pattern can contain KRISHNA, so you can figure out the total number of ways the pattern can not contain KRISHNA. I'm not sure how you get the 6!7! in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you allow say **SHINRAK** as a **KRISHNA** pattern, there are $7!$ of these, giving you $12!-7!6!$, otherwise it's just $12!-6!$.